# Rails Migrating Foreign Keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration

I have recently discovered that a relationship between two of my tables is wrong and I would like to make the necessary changes - this involves dropping a foreign key on my accommodations table and adding a foreign key on my users table.

I have created a migration file using:

```
rails g migration ForeignKeyAdjustment
```

and then added this to the new migration file:

```
class ForeignKeyAdjustment < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    remove_column :accommodations, :user_id
    add_column :users, :accommodation_id, :integer
  end
end
```

I then ran the migration using:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

and then used the console to check the column names in each table and the changes have not taken effect!

```
rails console
```

and

```
User.column_names
```

What am I missing?

p.s. would it be a major issue if I just deleted my models and the database migration files and generated new models from the terminal? It wouldn't take me long and no important data to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Have you established Active Record associations?  That will allow you to map the records from one table to another.  Otherwise the column name is just an arbitrary name in the table.

Did you add the foreign key attribute to your model?
this creates the attribute for the existing model through in attr accessible

these can be some of the potential problems

guide on associations
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

i would also edit the title of the question to something like "Migrating Foreign Keys" so other people can find answers to similar questions.

Comment: Well originally i had the associations yes - but to make these changes do i make the new associations without the proper fields in place

Comment: what are you models? you have to add the attributes and the has_many, belongs to, etc to both models; ForeignKeyAdjustment model and the other model.

Comment: before the migration you mean - will this actually make a difference?

Comment: if one of the models is user and is associated with the model that has column_names (in your example) you need the association established to call User.method_in_the_other_model.

Comment: Yes I realise this - the issue was to do with migration but never mind I have solved it now. I used 3.3 of this webpage: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#changing-tables